# Using regex, or something else, to find two specific upper case letters right next to eachother in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, loops

I'm gonna have dynamic upper case letters, meaning they change often, they are all the abbreviations of the states. (CA,NV,NY, etc.)

What I need to do, is somehow take the characters from those abbreviations, that are stored in a window variable, maybe by for-looping?

Then I need to place those two upper case letters and place them into a regex function that is able to scan strings to see if they exist at all in the string, as long as they exist right next to eachother.

Appreciate any help you may offer.

Here's my for loop to break apart the two capital letters so I can insert them into the regex function.

```
function find_capitals(x){
  var arr = []
  for(var i = 0; i<x.length;i++){
    arr.push(x[i]);
  }
  return arr
}
var checker = find_capitals('CA')
console.log(checker)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use indexOf() function to check whether a substring('CA','NV','NY') exists in a string like:

```
var input = "Android gave new life to Java";
var isFound = input.indexOf("Android") !=-1? true: false; //true
```

in your case it will be:

```
var input = "NewYork NY";
var isFound = input.indexOf("NY") !=-1? true: false; //true
```

[for reference](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/10/how-to-check-if-string-contains-another-substring-in-java-indexof-example.html#axzz6jPJvUOvK)